# what is this encoding in postgres database and how can I decode it

Tags: postgresql, utf-8, character-encoding

I have a legacy postgres 8.4 database that I am pulling foreign addresses out of. The encoding on the database is UTF-8 and most of the special characters appear fine as normal readable characters, e.g: `Á, É, Í, Ó, Ü`

However there are thousands of records that use some other encoding for these characters, they all start with a non-printable `STX` char and then the sequence: `6#x` followed by 1 or 2 hexadecimal chars.

E.g: `CUAUHT6#xc9;MOC` which should be: `CUAUHTÉMOC`

I tried using on-line "decoders" to identify this gibberish but did not have any luck. However, I was able to identify the following based on the city names and referencing postal codes:

```
existing          should be
--------          ---------
6#xc1;            Á
6#xc9;            É
6#xcd;            Í
6#xd3;            Ó
6#xdc;            Ü
6#xd;             " " (space)
```

The data appears to be stored in the database like this. Though admittedly, I am new to postgres so could be missing something fairly obvious.

Short of finding and replacing all instances, is this an identifiable encoding that has a standard `decode` function?

Comment: Are you sure that it is `6#xc1;` and not `&#xc1;`? The latter would be an HTML encoding.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe definitely is a `6` proceeded by the non-printable `STX` char. Though I think you are right. I've found a few more that are definitely html entities with a funky `STX6` start instead of `&`. Seems to come from bad inputting... not an actual encoding. I think I can just swap all `STX6` for `&` and call it a day. Thanks!

Comment: The '&' Unicode value is U+0026, so the '6#x' mistake could have been related to that somehow